# Select into multilevel type in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to find out if there is a way to bulk collect into a multi-level type in Oracle.  The example below should help in explaining the concept of what I am trying to do.

There is a source table with a denormalised list of counties and towns:

```
create table county_town (county varchar2(20), town varchar2(20));

insert into county_town values ('Surrey', 'Dorking');
insert into county_town values ('Surrey', 'Woking');
insert into county_town values ('Surrey', 'Guildford');
insert into county_town values ('Oxfordshire', 'Thame');
insert into county_town values ('Oxfordshire', 'Abingdon');
```

What I want to do is load this into a multilevel type that looks like this:

```
create type towns_typ as table of varchar2(20);
create type counties_typ as object (country varchar2(20), towns towns_type);    
create type nt_counties_typ as table of counties_typ;

l_county_data nt_counties_typ
```

Is there some way that I can write a SELECT statement to BULK collect this data into l_county_data from the table county_town ?  If BULK COLLECT cant be used is there another way to do this simply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, like here:

```
declare 
  l_county_data nt_counties_typ;
begin
  select counties_typ(county, cast(collect(town) as towns_typ))
  bulk collect into l_county_data
  from county_town
  group by county;

  dbms_output.put_line(l_county_data(2).county);
end;
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=46ec6298ee6a0dc05049e99447e58128)